# Getting a JSON file from R to Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

What I have, is a JSON file created by R, through the `jsonlite` library.

I used these commands:

```
a = something
b = something
c = list(a,b)
res = toJSON(c)
```

What I want, is to save this JSON in a file and read it in MATLAB. What type of file should I make with the `save()` function of R, in order to achieve this? And what commands/functions should I use in MATLAB to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Matlab R2016b or later, you can use `jsondecode` to read in a JSON file simply. See the doc: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html. So you would do:

```
>> jsondecode(fileread('yourfile.json'));
```

If you have Matlab R2016a or earlier, you can use JSONlab: https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab. To read a file with JSONlab, at the Matlab prompt you will have to do:

```
>> addpath <<path/to/jsonlab>>;
>> loadjson('yourfile.json');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the JSON out to a file from R, but will not help you loading and formatting on the MATLAB side:

```
write(R_file_Json, "your_data.json")
```

If it is currently in a list, and not yet ready for saving, using `jsonlite` you can export it to JSON with the following:

```
R_file_Json <- toJSON(your_list)
```

You should verify the schema before you save it and try to open it in MATLAB just to save yourself formatting headaches on the other side.

Comment: I have done the ```toJSON(list)``` command. The file is JSON. How do I open it in MATLAB though?

Comment: updated my question since it wasnt that clear to begin with. @sconfluentus

Comment: This will be a simple text file that you can read into Matlab, then use a Matlab function to convert the JSON.

Answer (score -2):

JSON is a universal format. You can write the file as a string literal (plain text) and then read it back with matlab as a string and do the conversion.